# List Ansible inventory and use it in a playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to know if it's possible to list all the node present in the inventory to write them in a file ?

exemple:

- I have 5 node present in my inventory list
- In a playbook I need to list them
- to copy them at the end of a file

I need to do this because I use a reverse proxy and it's to enter my new node automatically in my vhost file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- name: write hosts
  copy: 
    dest: <your-name>.txt
    content: {{ groups.ungrouped | union(groups.<some-groups-you-have>) | join("\n") }}
```